# Automation framework for partly native and partly mobile web application

Tags: android, automation, web, mobile

I have an Android app which will be installed on a device. The main requirement of the native Android app will be trigger a mobile web app (on Chrome) which will have functions for user interaction.

Which automation framework can help me write UI tests where the native Android app triggers the mobile web app on Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I've used Selenium to test the HTML part of a Cordova app for over 4 years, so that's a good starting point.

Going to the app environment, [Appium](http://appium.io/) is the best approach for a hybrid app. It's the "Selenium for apps".